# iOS Swift - Image from ScrollView disappears after adding filter

Tags: ios, swift, filter, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to build a photo editing app. I have a scrollview with an imageView inside. After adding a filter to that image, the image disappears from the scrollView. What is the problem?

Adding filter function:

```
    func filter1(image: UIImage){

    let beginImage = CIImage(image: image)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)

    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
    self.imageView.image = newImage

    centerScrollViewContents()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Imageview.setneedsDisplay()
```

Or

```
ScrollView.setneedsDisplay()
```

The reason for that is to trigger these views to redraw their content.